# Software recommendation for plotting data from lab tests

Tags: visualization, plotting

I have several files of data created by LabView of hydraulic pressure testing over the course of a few days. This data is mostly time with various pressure and temperature measurements.

Can you recommend software that will plot several hours worth of data and then let me zoom/pan and select certain intervals? I need to comb through the data a find examples of acceptable pressure holds. Excel is inadequate for this task.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. How familiar are you with programming languages? If you don't mind writing some lines I would suggest to use [Python](https://www.python.org/) with [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) or [R](https://www.r-project.org/) with [ggplot](http://ggplot2.org/).

Comment: LabView can do this already.

Comment: It really depends how much data (in either number of data points or megabyte) is "several hours worth of data". Can you edit your question to include this information?

Comment: What is the input file format? Is it csv or LabViews proprietary binary format?

Answer (score 2):

GnuPlot http://www.gnuplot.info/ is quite complete and good for generating various types of graphs.

There is a gallery of the different types of graphs  that it can generate http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/ (as well as example scripts to generate them)

If you are using Linux, then its probably already in your distribution (else it can be installed using the package manager)

If you are using Windows, there are some windows builds available there:
http://ctan.ijs.si/mirror/w32tex/w32/

Answer (score 2):

As @nicoguaro mentioned in his comment. If you are familiar with python programming language, I would recommend   matplotlib. It is a Python-based plotting library. You can plot  various types of graphs such as line, scattered,histogram, etc. You can also make 3d plots.

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) is a gallery of plots produced by matplotlib.

Matplotlib also has  a large community so you can find answers to your questions easily.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial Software:

- Matlab
- Mathematica

Free Open Source Tools:

- Matplotlib(Python)
- GNUPlot

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. There are, definitely, more commercial and open source tools for doing this. Can you provide an explanation of why this suggestions are good?